# Xt (X Tools Intrinsic) Toolkit. What is an application context?

Tags: linux, user-interface, gtk

I found a GTK-Xt wrapper from SourceForge, that basically allows the creation of an XtAppContext app_context variable from GTK+.

What is the purpsoe of this app_context? Will I be able to use Xt functions in conjunction with GTK+ ?

Thanks, friends.

Comment: Why do you want to use Xt functions and not pure GTK+ ?

Comment: I am trying to leverage existing software that utilizes Xt.  Just wanted to know if this was possible; if not, then I will be forced to rewrite parts of the software to fit my needs

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice I would suggest you program in GTK+ directly. This way all the low-level stuff is abstracted. In the future your app also is upgraded automatically by improvements in the GTK implementation (e.g. XLIB to XCB)

Xt is really old, undocumented and not even used by graphical toolkits today.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Toolkit_Intrinsics